# Saving/Retrieving checkboxes in js php/html array

Tags: javascript, php

I can save the checkboxes value just fine in my sql database, but when I go to load the data, EVERYTHING is checked.  Does anyone know why that is?

Problem Area :

```
 <td><input type="checkbox" <?php if(isset($item['staged'])) echo "checked=\"checked\""?> data-type="checkbox" name="data[InvoiceDetail][<?php echo $key;?>][staged]" id="staged_<?php echo $key+1?>" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
```

Full HTML Code :

```
<?php if(isset($invoice['InvoiceDetail'])&&!empty($invoice['InvoiceDetail'])){?>
    <?php foreach ( $invoice['InvoiceDetail'] as $key=>$item){?>
        <tr>
            <td> <input class="case" type="checkbox"/> </td>
            <td><input value="<?php echo isset($item['product_id']) ? $item['product_id']: ''; ?>" type="text" data-type="productCode" name="data[InvoiceDetail][<?php echo $key;?>][product_id]" id="itemNo_<?php echo $key+1?>" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
            <td><input value="<?php echo isset($item['productName']) ? $item['productName']: ''; ?>" type="text" data-type="productName" name="data[InvoiceDetail][<?php echo $key;?>][productName]" id="itemName_<?php echo $key+1?>" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
            <td><input value="<?php echo isset($item['price']) ? $item['price']: ''; ?>" type="number" name="data[InvoiceDetail][<?php echo $key;?>][price]" id="price_<?php echo $key+1?>" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
            <td>
                <input value="<?php echo isset($item['quantity']) ? $item['quantity']: ''; ?>" type="number" name="data[InvoiceDetail][<?php echo $key;?>][quantity]" id="quantity_<?php echo $key+1?>" class="form-control changesNo quanyityChange" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
                <input value="<?php echo isset($item['quantityInStock']) ? $item['quantityInStock']: ''; ?>"  type="hidden" id="stock_<?php echo $key+1?>" autocomplete="off"/>
                <input value="0" type="hidden" id="stockMaintainer_<?php echo $key+1?>" name="data[InvoiceDetail][<?php echo $key;?>][stockMaintainer]" autocomplete="off"/>
                <input value="<?php echo isset($item['quantity']) ? $item['quantity']: ''; ?>" type="hidden" id="previousQuantity_<?php echo $key+1?>" autocomplete="off"/>
                <input value="<?php echo isset($item['id']) ? $item['id']: ''; ?>" type="hidden" id="invoiceDetailId_<?php echo $key+1?>" autocomplete="off"/>
            </td>
            <td><input value="<?php echo $item['price']*$item['quantity']; ?>" type="number" id="total_<?php echo $key+1?>" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" <?php if(isset($item['staged'])) echo "checked=\"checked\""?> data-type="checkbox" name="data[InvoiceDetail][<?php echo $key;?>][staged]" id="staged_<?php echo $key+1?>" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>

        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
<?php }else{?>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="data[InvoiceDetail][0][product_id]" id="itemNo_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
        <td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="data[InvoiceDetail][0][productName]" id="itemName_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="data[InvoiceDetail][0][price]" id="price_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="data[InvoiceDetail][0][quantity]" id="quantity_1" class="form-control changesNo quanyityChange" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
            <input type="hidden" id="stock_1" autocomplete="off"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="data[InvoiceDetail][0][stockMaintainer]" id="stockMaintainer_1" autocomplete="off"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="previousQuantity_1" autocomplete="off"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="invoiceDetailId_1" autocomplete="off"/>
        </td>
        <td><input type="number" id="total_1" class="form-control totalLinePrice addNewRow" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
        <td><input value="1" type="checkbox" name="data[InvoiceDetail][0][staged]" id="staged_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>                                 
        </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Corresponding SQL Code :

```
private function saveInvoiceDetail(array $invoice_details, $invoice_id = ''){ //$this->pre($invoice_details);
        $deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM invoice_details WHERE invoice_id = $invoice_id";
        mysqli_query($this->_con, $deleteQuery);

        foreach ($invoice_details as $invoice_detail){
            $product_id = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con, trim( $invoice_detail['product_id'] ) );
            $productName = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con, trim( $invoice_detail['productName'] ) );
            $quantity = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con, trim( $invoice_detail['quantity'] ) );
            $price = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con, trim( $invoice_detail['price'] ) );
            $staged = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con, trim( $invoice_detail['staged'] ) );
            $stockMaintainer = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con, trim( $invoice_detail['stockMaintainer'] ) );

            if( $stockMaintainer != 0){
                $updateQuery = "UPDATE products SET quantityInStock = ( quantityInStock - ($stockMaintainer) ) WHERE productCode = '$product_id'";
                mysqli_query($this->_con, $updateQuery);
            }

            $query = "INSERT INTO invoice_details (`id`, `invoice_id`, `product_id`, productName, `quantity`, `price`, `staged`)
                    VALUES (NULL, '$invoice_id', '$product_id', '$productName', '$quantity', '$price', '$staged')";

            //$this->pre($query);
            mysqli_query($this->_con, $query);
        }

    }

    private function restructure_array(array $arr)
    {
        $result = array();
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($value); $i++) {
                $result[$i][$key] = $value[$i];
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function getInvoice( $id = ''){
        if( !empty( $id ) ){
            $query = "SELECT * FROM invoices where uuid ='$id'";
            $result = mysqli_query($this->_con, $query);
            $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $invoiceDetail = array();
            $clientDetail = array();
            if(isset( $data['client_id'] ) && !empty( $data['client_id'] ))$clientDetail = $this->getClientDetail($data['client_id'] );

            if( isset( $data['id'] ) && !empty( $data['id'] )){
                $invoice_id = $data['id'];
                $query1 = "SELECT InvoiceDetail.id, Product.productName, Product.quantityInStock, InvoiceDetail.product_id, InvoiceDetail.productName, InvoiceDetail.quantity,              
                        InvoiceDetail.staged, InvoiceDetail.price FROM invoice_details InvoiceDetail LEFT JOIN products 
                        Product ON InvoiceDetail.product_id = Product.productCode WHERE InvoiceDetail.invoice_id = $invoice_id ORDER by InvoiceDetail.id ASC";
                $invoiceDetailResult = mysqli_query($this->_con, $query1);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($invoiceDetailResult)){
                    array_push($invoiceDetail, $row);
                }

            }else{
                throw new Exception( FIELDS_MISSING );
            }

            if(empty($invoiceDetail)){
                $result = array( 'Invoice'=> $data, 'Client' => $clientDetail);
            }else{
                $result = array( 'Invoice'=> $data, 'Client' => $clientDetail, 'InvoiceDetail'=> $invoiceDetail);
            }
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: so what's in `$item['staged']`? an empty string is still "set" and would cause you to output a checked attribute.

Comment: @MarcB $item['staged'] should be either a 1 or a 0, 1 if it is checked.  The value "1" is saved just fine into my sql database, but the program does not read "1" and output a check to the checkbox, it just checks everything :P

Comment: what about `0`? that's still a "set" value. isset is basically "exists and the value is not null". you should probably test for `!= 1` or something instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$item['staged']` will be `0` or `1` then `isset()` on its own is probably the wrong function to use on its own.

I assume this is processing data from the database, so its not like when you process a checkbox from the `$_POST/$_GET` arrays, as it will always be there even if it was unchecked on the screen because you should then have written 0 to the database if it was unchecked on the screen.

Try

```
<td>
   <input type="checkbox" <?php if(isset($item['staged']) && $item['staged'] == 1) echo "checked=\"checked\""?> 
         data-type="checkbox" 
         name="data[InvoiceDetail][<?php echo $key;?>][staged]" 
         id="staged_<?php echo $key+1?>" 
         class="form-control autocomplete_txt" 
         autocomplete="off">
</td>
```

In fact you can probably loose the `isset()` completely and just code

```
<td>
   <input type="checkbox" <?php if($item['staged'] == 1) echo "checked=\"checked\""?> 
         data-type="checkbox" 
         name="data[InvoiceDetail][<?php echo $key;?>][staged]" 
         id="staged_<?php echo $key+1?>" 
         class="form-control autocomplete_txt" 
         autocomplete="off">
</td>
```

***Reply to comment***

Like I said above, when processing that data from the `$_POST/$_GET` arrays a checkbox that is not checked will not exist in the  `$_POST/$_GET` arrays so then you have to test for its existance using `isset()`

For example :

```
$staged = isset( $invoice_detail['staged']) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: This works PERFECT when it comes to reading the checkbox from the sql database, but for some odd reason, BREAKS the saving :P

Comment: Is that any more help

Comment: So plain english(sorry, learning php), the above isset sql code means :
if invoice detail(staged) is set, check to see if it is 0 or one and proceed?

Comment: Thats ok, If you mean this line `isset( $invoice_detail['staged']) ? 1 : 0 ` it means if `$invoice_detail['staged']` is set i.e. exists then I should store 1 into the database, else I shoudl store 0 into the database

Comment: Actually as you are generating the data value 0 or 1 you dont need the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` stuff at all. See amendment

Comment: That makes perfect sense :P.  Now, can you change the 1 and 0 into text, such as this :
isset( $invoice_detail['staged']) ? apples : bananas 
or this :
isset( $invoice_detail['staged']) ? $apples : $bananas

Comment: Yes you could do `$var = $invoice_detail['staged']) ? 'apples' : 'bananas';` or `$var = $invoice_detail['staged']) ? $apples : $bananas;`

Comment: Awesome, THANK YOU very much for your help!